# Access the database using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have @di object and drop down as below.

```
<select class="form-control input-lg dm-recipients" id="recipients" name="recipients[]" multiple="multiple">
  <% if @di.size >= 1 and !@di.include?("data") %>
    <% @di.each do |d| %>
     <% d['recipients'].each do |r| %>               
       <option value="<%= r %>"></option>               
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
</select>
```

here In my @di object has variable call 'recipients' and it save list of recipient IDs within an array. below is an example.

> "RECIPIENTS"=>["D524CD29-0EA7-4749-93D3-E9B7FB7930D1", "1EA8AF49-DC88-4857-9B40-2D467C0C2E65"]

These are user ids. I have user table which save user details. I want to print the name of user which has above IDs. How can I do this. I am very new for rails.

Comment: Same question as in your previous deleted post: how do you initialize your `@di` object? As you can see in your `recipients`, you don't have any name, which means you've got something wrong before even trying to construct your select.

Comment: @romainsalles yes you are correct. I just save user id. I want fetch user details from user table using this recipients values. Because recipients save the user IDs

Comment: After the `<% @di.each do |d| %>`: `<% users = User.where(id: d['recipients']).pluck(:id, :name).to_h %>`. And then, `users[r]` to get the name in your option?

Comment: @romainsalles can I access user table this way?

Comment: If you don't know the answer to this question, please re-read Rails tutorials because I won't be able to help you without giving you a complete course ^^'

Comment: @romainsalles I have members_controller where load the all users. Can I use that for compare recipients with user and fetch the user data